# Is it normal to for Firefox to re-render a webpage that has been downloaded?

Tags: windows-10, firefox

- Windows 10: never put to 'sleep' because of Win10 issues
- Firefox 49.0.1

When this box was stood-up 10 months ago with Firefox (FF), performance was snappy \ good.  In the last few months, I have noticed a lag in performance.

EXAMPLE: I have opened up 6 webpages and confirmed that each was downloaded: each has its own tab.  Each time I switch between a tab it can take 1-30 seconds to render the page: it seems to be downloading an creating the page.  It's unclear if it is downloading the page from the source or from cached memory.  The machine has a SSD and 16GB of RAM: it should not be a hardware bottleneck.

I also noticed that sometimes there is significant lag from when I type in characters and when they are displayed.  I am also using FF on Ubuntu and it does not suffer any of these symptoms.

When I installed, this was not the norm.  Why is FF behaving this way and what corrective action can be taken?

Comment: Just to be clear: when FF starts it doesn't load tabs until they are selected. Does page loading occur every time you switch tabs, or only the first time after start? Or maybe after sleep? And on all tabs, or only some of them? Many web pages auto-reload, which is inhibited during sleep.

Comment: @AFH: good comments and questions.  Attempted to answer your questions by modifying original posts.